# Display items in order including image WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to display the products/items within a WooCommerce order using the following php, but the items are not being shown.

The code I am using is an adaptation of this: [Get cart item name, quantity all details woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce/28576861)

Using the original code from the question above also does not display anything on my page.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php  


        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        //product image
        $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $getProductDetail->get_image(); // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<p style="font-size:10pt;">'.$_product->post_title.'</p><td><p style="font-size:10pt;">x'. $values['quantity'] . '</p></td>'; 
        echo '</td></tr>';
        };
   ?>
```

The full page code is here:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Store
*/
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('manage_options')) wp_die('This page is private.');


?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>
      <?php _e('Store Queue'); ?>
    </title>

  </head>

  <body id="driverqueue">
    <header>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

          <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </header>
    <section>
      <?php 

  global $woocommerce;


  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
  );
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

  $customer_orders = $my_query->posts;

  foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
   $order = new WC_Order();

   $order->populate($customer_order);
   $orderdata = (array) $order;

   // $orderdata Array will have Information. for e.g Shippin firstname, Lastname, Address ... and MUCH more.... Just enjoy!
  }




  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    ?>







        <table class="ordertable" id="<?php echo $order_id; ?>">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Order #
                <?php echo $order_id; ?> &mdash;
                  <time datetime="<?php the_time('c'); ?>">
                    <?php echo the_time('d/m/Y g:i:s A'); ?>
                  </time>
              </p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr>

                  <?php  


            global $woocommerce;
            $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

            foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product = $values['data']->post;
            //product image
            $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo $getProductDetail->get_image(); // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<p style="font-size:10pt;">'.$_product->post_title.'</p><td><p style="font-size:10pt;">x'. $values['quantity'] . '</p></td>'; 
            echo '</td></tr>';
            };
              ?>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>
                <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_start', $order );

            $actions = array();


            if ( $order->has_status( array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing' ) ) ) {
              $actions['complete'] = array(
                'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=awaiting-shipment&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                'name'      => __( 'Complete', 'woocommerce' ),
                'action'    => "complete"
              );
            };

            $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', $actions, $order );

            foreach ( $actions as $action ) {
              printf( '<a class="button %s" href="%s" data-tip="%s">%s</a>', esc_attr( $action['action'] ), esc_url( $action['url'] ), esc_attr( $action['name'] ), esc_attr( $action['name'] ) );
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', $order );
          ?>
              </p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <form action="">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ordercollected" value="0" />
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endwhile; ?>

    </section>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This was added in by the first person that edited the post. You are correct, the spaces do need to be removed, but this does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this using info from the following link with the adapted code below:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180075/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-product-info

```
<?php  

foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {

        //uncomment the following to see the full data
               // echo '<pre>';
               // print_r($lineItem);
               // echo '</pre>';
                $product_id = $lineItem['product_id'];
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                echo '<tr><td>' . $product->get_image() . '</td>'; // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )
                echo '<td>' . 'Product: ' . $lineItem['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td> x' . $lineItem['qty'] . '</td></tr>';
              }

              ?>
```

Comment: Also, you can display the product images with carousel, see this repo: `https://github.com/johnzenith/wordpress/blob/master/woocommerce/display-product-images.php`