# Get Added to card Product ID in Woocommerece

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-rest-api

I am creating a Custom Checkout Page , here I want to show the customer;  the Product they already added into their cart. How can I show the Product here which has already Added to cart?

** I want o get a Shortcode / Product ID which is already on Cart

Comment: Hey @Shohrab Hossain! Are you customising the `form-checkout.php` page? There you should have access to all the items that have been added to the cart. See [how to override templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) for more details. Would it also be possible to include in your question more details of what you are trying to achieve (with any relevant code)?

Comment: Kindly check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce#answer-28576861