# Warning: Creating default object from empty value, in PHP 8 I get CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "length" on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, php-7.4, php-8

WordPress 5.9.2 and WooCommerce 6.3.1
Using this code:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $address['suburb']   = $package['destination']['city'];
    $address['state']    = $package['destination']['state'];
    $address['postcode'] = $package['destination']['postcode'];
    $address['country']  = $package['destination']['country'];

    $i           = 0;
    $totalweight = 0;
    $totalprice  = 0;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $q        = 1;
        while ( $values['quantity'] >= $q ) {
            $products[ $i ]->length = $_product->length;
            $products[ $i ]->height = $_product->height;
            $products[ $i ]->width  = $_product->width;
            $products[ $i ]->weight = $_product->weight;
            $totalweight           += $_product->weight;
            $totalprice            += $_product->get_price();
            $q++;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

relating to length, height, width and weight:
`$products[$i]->length = $_product->length;`

Comment: Well it means that `$products[$i]` is null (or not set at all), for the current value of $i. I don't see where `$products` is supposed to come from here at all, it does not get passed into the method as a parameter, is not imported via `global`, and does not get created before those lines either.

Comment: It is an extension of WC_Shipping_Method, the code has always worked and was able to retrieve/obtain the products dimensions and weight to use in a API request, it may have had a warning for a while although in PHP 8 it fails, just though I would ask if anyone had run into the same issue, looks like a will be recoding if I cannot find a fix.:(

Comment: I can't tell if those `$products` are supposed to exist at this point already, or if they should get created - if the latter, then try `if(!isset($products[$i])) { $products[$i] = new stdClass; }` as first line inside the while loop.

Comment: `$products` is un-declared as an array, aside from that, `$_product`  which should be defined isn't.  Look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce as it would appear you are getting the `$_product` incorrectly.

Comment: @CBroe Your last suggestion worked

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's create a standalone example that can be tested more easily:

```
class Example {
    public $length, $height, $width, $weight;
    
    public function __construct($length, $height, $width, $weight) {
        $this->length = $length;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
    
    public function get_price() {
        return 1.23;
    }
}

$sample_data = [
    42 => ['quantity' => 2, 'data' => new Example(42, 42, 42, 42)],
    69 => ['quantity' => 1, 'data' => new Example(69, 69, 69, 69)],
];

$i           = 0;
$totalweight = 0;
$totalprice  = 0;

foreach ( $sample_data as $item_id => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $q        = 1;
    while ( $values['quantity'] >= $q ) {
        $products[ $i ]->length = $_product->length;
        $products[ $i ]->height = $_product->height;
        $products[ $i ]->width  = $_product->width;
        $products[ $i ]->weight = $_product->weight;
        $totalweight           += $_product->weight;
        $totalprice            += $_product->get_price();
        $q++;
        $i++;
    }
}

var_dump($products);
```

Now we can see what this did on older versions of PHP, for instance [using this handy tool which runs the same code on multiple versions](https://3v4l.org/1Imu2).

The output in PHP 7.4 is this:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /in/1Imu2 on line 31

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /in/1Imu2 on line 31

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /in/1Imu2 on line 31
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (4) {
    ["length"]=>
    int(42)
    ["height"]=>
    int(42)
    ["width"]=>
    int(42)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(42)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["length"]=>
    int(42)
    ["height"]=>
    int(42)
    ["width"]=>
    int(42)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(42)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
    ["length"]=>
    int(69)
    ["height"]=>
    int(69)
    ["width"]=>
    int(69)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(69)
  }
}
```

So we can see that what's happening is that for each item, the code is implicitly creating a `stdClass` object, before assigning properties on it. The fix is therefore to make that creation explicit by writing `$products[ $i ] = new stdClass;` just before `$products[ $i ]->length = $_product->length;` While we're at it, we should also create `$products` as an empty array with `$products = [];` before the `foreach` loop.

[Running our modified code in the same tool](https://3v4l.org/8Fgpg) we can see that it now gives the same result on every PHP version from PHP 5.4 up to and including 8.1, with no Warnings.